# Use / modify array of objects to use in ngRepeat for dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use an array of objects to show in a drop down list. Here is the json file

```
{
"list": [
{
"product": "Test1 ",
"Name": "Test 1 Name",
"countries": [{"countryId": 53,"countryName": "Unites States"}]
},
{
"product": "Test 2",
"Name": "Test 2 Name",
 "countries": [{"countryId": 54,"countryName": "Canada"}]
}    
]

}
```

I would like to show a drop down that list the countries using the countryName to show in the dropdown and use countryId as value.

Comment: It looks like you're asking people to do the work for you. You're not asking a question. What have you done already? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should first try some code, and if you fail to achieve what you tried, then ask a question.**

Here is an answer assuming you tried some code.

Use `select as`

**select as:**

Using `select as` will bind the result of the select expression to the model, but the value of the  and  html elements will be either the `index (for array data sources)` or `property name (for object data sources)` of the value within the collection. If a track by expression is used, the result of that expression will be set as the value of the option and select elements.

[This is the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-options="item.countries[0].countryId as item.countries[0].countryName for item in records.list" ng-model="selected">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>


<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = {
"list": [
{
"product": "Test1 ",
"Name": "Test 1 Name",
"countries": [{"countryId": 53,"countryName": "Unites States"}]
},
{
"product": "Test 2",
"Name": "Test 2 Name",
 "countries": [{"countryId": 54,"countryName": "Canada"}]
}    
]

}

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [select documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). Angular has a couple ways of doing `select` inputs.

Any way you do it, you will need to save the "list" object to $scope in your JS file. E.g. `$scope.list = [...]`

Then, one way of doing the select is using `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="item.name for item in list track by item.product" ng-model="userChoice"></select>
```

Your other option is to use ng-repeat on a regular option tag:

```
<select ng-model="userChoice">
<option ng-repeat="item in list" value="item.product">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

These are roughly equivalent, but not exactly. You will find that if you use `ng-repeat` it is difficult to have a "default" option selected. If you use `ng-options` it is difficult to add custom fields that are not in the model, like "other" or "none".